# ABCPDF Stamp() does not honor font settings on fields

Tags: abcpdf

After inspecting the information of individual fields attached to the doc.Form I see the expected font settings.  However, once Stamp() is called and the PDF rendering completes the font size is not retained, although the font itself and some relative sizing is.

Versions: 7 and 8

Additionally, despite having :

- doc.Form.NeedAppearances
- doc.Form.GenerateAppearances
- doc.Form.FormatFields

set true, the system appears to ignore Adobe JavaScript such as:

```
getField('MyField').textSize = 12
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Should anyone else encounter this error, you should start by checking the size of the fields on the PDF you are filling.  If the field sizes are not deemed large enough to hold your selected font then ABCPDF scales the font to a size of its choosing.  Once the fields are large enough to contain the font, by ABC's standards, then the font size will be limited by the settings you choose.  In this case you should oversize your fields whenever possible.